# Stopping web audio drum loop with getElementById and addEventListener

Tags: javascript, for-loop, getelementbyid, addeventlistener, web-audio-api

I am trying to make a metronome that slowly ramps up the speed, allowing me do to excersises without having to stop playing to turn my handheld metronome up. I'm using a loop to play each measure and am trying to get a stop button to work using `document.getElementById` and `addEventListener` to look for a click on the stop button each pass of the loop. Using `console.log`, I can see each click of the stop button showing up, but when I try to stop the beat loop using `source.noteOff(context.currentTime)` I get nothing. Any suggestions or points in the right direction would be appreciated.

html is:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///Users/katri/rails_projects/metronome/metronome2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///Users/katri/rails_projects/metronome/buffer-loader.js"></script>

<input type="button" onClick="startLoop();" value="Play Loop!">
<input type="button" id="stop" value="Stop Loop!">
</html>
```

and the javascript in question is:

```
var startTime = context.currentTime;
var tempo = 80; // BPM (beats per minute)
var eighthNoteTime = (60 / tempo) / 2;
var totalTime = startTime;

for (var bar = 0; bar < 2; bar++) {
  document.getElementById('stop').addEventListener('click', function() {
  source.noteOff(context.currentTime);
  });

  eighthNoteTime = (60 / tempo) / 2;

  // Play the bass (kick) drum on beats 1, 3, 4, 5 & 7
  playSound(kick, totalTime);
  playSound(kick, totalTime + 1 * eighthNoteTime);
  playSound(kick, totalTime + 3 * eighthNoteTime);
  playSound(kick, totalTime + 4 * eighthNoteTime);
  playSound(kick, totalTime + 5 * eighthNoteTime);
  playSound(kick, totalTime + 7 * eighthNoteTime);

  // Play the snare drum on beats 3, 7
  playSound(snare, totalTime + 2 * eighthNoteTime);
  playSound(snare, totalTime + 6 * eighthNoteTime);

  totalTime = totalTime + 8 * eighthNoteTime;
  tempo = tempo+5;
  }
}

function playSound(soundIndex, time) {
  var source = context.createBufferSource();
  source.buffer = bufferLoader.bufferList[soundIndex];
  source.connect(context.destination);
  source.noteOn(time);
    }
```

Comment: Could you make a fiddle out of this? To show the current functionality working? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Here it is but the loop part that works for me doesn't work on fiddle b/c it doesn't have access to the two sound files used in the loop. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/dponeill2004/kJt4N/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can't really take this approach directly, because your general approach is to schedule a measure's worth of beats at a time, and while you're doing that, you're forgetting the BufferSourceNode objects (i.e., you're not maintaining references to them - the newly created objects pass out of scope at the end of playSound()).  This is a handy way to fire-and-forget sound playback, but it's not going to bode well for your application.  You can do one of two things:

1) Take a more just-in-time approach to scheduling the beats, so you don't have a whole measure's worth of beats buffered up.  Go read the article I wrote at the beginning of the year on scheduling in Web Audio: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/.

2) Maintain pointers to the buffer source nodes so you can disconnect them, or (considerably easier) connect() them through a gain node you can silence (set .gain.value to 0) when you hit "stop".  I presume you're missing a bunch of code, also, to CONTINUE to ramp up the speed and play more than just two measures, right? That will start getting a bit messy, because of course you want the same kind of approach detailed in my article - you need to decide when to put more events in.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Chris. I actually discovered your article in the meantime and have been working from there. I'm pretty new to JavaScript so it probably helped doing this bad approach anyways. It gave me at least some familiarity with the web audio API so that your tutorial made sense. Cheers.